# Facebook Book Graph Object

Tags: facebook

Anyone knows how to get the isbn property of a "Book" facebook graph object?

from the graph explorer, the node for a graph object of id 107965322564266 (it's a book page) returns may information except for author and ISBN

```
{
   "name": "Good to Great", 
   "is_published": true, 
   "is_community_page": true, 
   "description": "Good to Great: Why Some Companies Make the Leap... and Others Don't is:", 
   "release_date": "October 16, 2001", 
   "talking_about_count": 201, 
   "category": "Book", 
   "id": "107965322564266", 
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Good-to-Great/107965322564266", 
   "likes": 71468
 }
```

Comment: You could perform an api mashup with https://developers.google.com/books/ to see if you can get the data from there

Answer (score 1):

That's not a book object, but rather a FB Page id  (`"is_community_page": true` and `"link"` contains `facebook.com/pages/`).

This is an example of a book object, a custom Open Graph object created by Goodreads:

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/905.The_Inner_Game_of_Tennis

A look at the page source / `og:` tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Inner Game of Tennis"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://photo.goodreads.com/books/1320565180msq/905.jpg"/>
<meta property="good_reads:isbn" content="0679778314">
<meta property="good_reads:page_num" content="134">
```

So the next thing to do is to find a specific og book object (you didn't say where/how you are sourcing all the books) and check the og tags.

Comment: Isn't there any other way instead of using metadata to refer to book object? think I have my own book repository with those info, and I want to create an action on Facebook passing a JS object with those parameters...